# Resizing Xterm window kills Django running in it

Tags: terminal, x11, django

I have a Django instance running in a terminal window. Any time I resize the window, the Django process dies ungracefully, leaving no record of it in the error_log file.

I tested it within ratpoison, xmonad and mwm. Both xterm and rxvt-unicode are affected. Hell, even PuTTY is affected!

Comment: Never experienced that myself. Does it happen in single-threaded mode (use `--nothreading`, while starting `python manage.py runserver`)? Cause python has bugs with multithreading not handling signals, e.g. SIGINT as KeyboardInterrupt exception appropriately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool. May be there's a similar bug with SIGWINCH, sent upon terminal resize?

Comment: Yes it does. I was using `runmodwsgi` before, but using `runserver` with `--nothreading` I get `OSError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call`. Thanks for your comment, now I know it is a Python issue. :7)

Comment: It could be helpful, if you provided information about your kernel version (is it preemptive?), python version and django version. It also might be related to your terminal, cause reads/writes to terminal are blocking and if they last too long for some reason, the signals coming in the meantime of terminal i/o system call can be discarded with this error as described here: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html

Comment: @Bob: Python 2.7, Django 1.7, kernel 2. (off the top of my head) 6. I'm not going to provide exact versions. I tested both remote and local terminals, as you can read in the OP, so I am disinclined to believe they are the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 1.7 was released September 2, 2014, end of life in December 1, 2015.

However, the problem is still topical.

This was a known issue with Python, documented in

- [PEP 475: Retry system calls failing with EINTR](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/) (29-July-2014)

Although Python (and Django) took no special action for `SIGWINCH`, it was still possible reads to be interrupted.  The fix in Python was committed for release 3.5 in [Issue23285](http://bugs.python.org/issue23285) , February 07, 2015.